# C# - reading in a bluetooth value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth

So I'm working on a project right now, and it should be a simple one, but I'm having difficulties.

I'm trying to read in data from a bluetooth dongle that is gathering info from a bluetooth weight scale. It measures data then fires the data to the PC.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I've tried searching for reference assemplbies, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to figure out how the device is communicating with the dongle in the first place, I would see if you can get an SDK or Reference from the manufacturer.

Comment: Maybe take a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362928(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: most of that guide is written in C though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are lucky your bluetooth dongle uses a **virtual serial port** to comunicte with computer. In your harwaremanager is there a virtual com-port if the dongle is online that disapears if the dongle is offline?

If yes you can use a terminalprogram to connect to the device and try out what happens. Modems, gps-devices and many other hardware uses virtual serial ports.

Answer (score 0):

Use my library [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/)? :-)  Bluetooth, OBEX and IrDA for .NET desktop/NETCF etc.

Seems that one of our users has done your scenario too: "Accepting a connection from a battery operated weight scale" http://inthehand.com/forums/p/3985/11429.aspx  He doesn't give great details however...